# Can't see wireless networks on laptop

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I can't see wirelass networks on my laptop.On other computers I can do that. I only know that model is HP Pavilion g series (I can't find other informations, my laptop don't have sticker with product number). I tried updating Atheros AR9485 wifi driver but the same thing is happening. I have Win 7 Ultimate 64 bit.

Comment: Do you have an wlan device in your device manager or at least an unknown device that could be a wlan adpater? Do you have a wlan switch on your notebook or a wlan lamp lighting?

Comment: Here is picture of my device menager http://www.deviantpics.com/image/YLc

Comment: Go to Start and search for System Information , once found and opened , you should be able to see the system manufacturar and model of your laptop on the right.

Comment: I don't have a wlan lamp or wlan switch on my laptop

Comment: Add the network manually, and try to connect.